# Hashmap slower after deserialization - Why?

Tags: java, hashmap, deserialization

I have a pretty large Hashmap (~250MB). Creating it takes about 50-55 seconds, so I decided to serialize it and save it to a file. Reading from the file takes about 16-17 seconds now.

The only problem is that lookups seems to be slower this way. I always thought that the hashmap is read from the file into the memory, so the performance should be the same compared to the case when I create the hashmap myself, right? Here is the code I am using to read the hashmap into a file:

```
File file = new File("omaha.ser");
FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(file);
ObjectInputStream s = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(f));
omahaMap = (HashMap<Long, Integer>) s.readObject();
s.close();
```

300 million lookups take about 3.1 seconds when I create the hashmap myself, and about 8.5 seconds when I read the same hashmap from file. Does anybody have an idea why? Am I overlooking something obvious?

**EDIT:**

I "measured" the time by just taking the time with System.nanotime(), so no proper benchmark method used. Here is the code:

```
public class HandEvaluationTest
{
    public static void Test()
    {

        HandEvaluation.populate5Card();
        HandEvaluation.populate9CardOmaha();


        Card[] player1cards = {new Card("4s"), new Card("2s"), new Card("8h"), new Card("4d")};
        Card[] player2cards = {new Card("As"), new Card("9s"), new Card("6c"), new Card("2h")};
        Card[] player3cards = {new Card("9h"), new Card("7h"), new Card("Kc"), new Card("Kh")};
        Card[] table = {new Card("2d"), new Card("2c"), new Card("3c"), new Card("5c"), new Card("4h")};


        int j=0, k=0, l=0;
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for(int p=0; p<100000000; p++)    {
           j = HandEvaluation.handEval9Hash(player1cards, table);
            k = HandEvaluation.handEval9Hash(player2cards, table);
            l = HandEvaluation.handEval9Hash(player3cards, table);

        }
        long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        System.out.println("Time needed: " + estimatedTime*Math.pow(10,-6) + "ms");
        System.out.println("Handstrength Player 1: " + j);
        System.out.println("Handstrength Player 2: " + k);
        System.out.println("Handstrength Player 3: " + l);
    }
}
```

The big hashmap work is done in HandEvaluation.populate9CardOmaha(). The 5-card one is small. The code for the big one:

```
 public static void populate9CardOmaha()
        {

            //Check if the hashmap is already there- then just read it and exit
            File hashmap = new File("omaha.ser");
            if(hashmap.exists())
            {
                try
                {
                    File file = new File("omaha.ser");
                    FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(file);
                    ObjectInputStream s = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(f));
                    omahaMap = (HashMap<Long, Integer>) s.readObject();
                    s.close();
                }
                catch(IOException ioex) {ioex.printStackTrace();}
                catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfex)
                {
                    System.out.println("Class not found");
                    cnfex.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }
                return;
            }

    // if it's not there, populate it yourself
    ... Code for populating hashmap ...
    // and then save it to file
          (

            try
            {
                File file = new File("omaha.ser");
                FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
                ObjectOutputStream s = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(f));
                s.writeObject(omahaMap);
                s.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ioex) {ioex.printStackTrace();}
        }
```

When i am populating it myself (= file is not here), lookups in the HandEvaluationTest.Test() take about 8 seconds instead of 3. Maybe it's just my very naive way of measuring the time elapsed?

Comment: It shouldn't impact AFAIK. It may be the way you are testing.

Comment: How did you benchmark this? Did you use [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)? [Caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/)? If you used _anything_ else, you can probably ignore your numbers entirely.

Comment: Interesting phenomenon. Do you, by chance, happen to have some [sscce](http://sscce.org/) for the benchmark code, so that we can try to reproduce this?

Comment: Just edited with additonal information. The cause could really be my very naive way of benchmarking it (I am pretty much a Java beginner)

Comment: Rerun your tests with jmh.

Comment: I will rerun with jmh, but that won't happen before Tuesday :( Will keep you updated then. Thank you meanwhile.

Answer (score 3):

This question was interesting, so I wrote my own test case to verify it. I found no difference in speed for a live lookup Vs one that was loaded from a serialized file. The program is available at the end of the post for anyone interested in running it.

- The methods were monitored using JProfiler.
- The serialized file is comparable to yours. ~ `230 MB`.
- Lookups in memory cost **1210** ms without any serialization

[image]

- After serializing the map and reading them again, the cost of lookups remained the same (well almost - **1224** ms)

[image]

- The profiler was tweaked to add minimal overhead in both scenarios.
- This was measured on `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06)` / `4 CPUs running at 1.7 Ghz` /  `4GB Ram 800 Mhz`

Measuring is tricky. I myself noticed the `8 second` lookup time that you described, but guess what else I noticed when that happened.

#### GC activity

[image]

Your measurements are probably picking that up too. If you isolate the measurements of `Map.get()` alone you'll see that the results are comparable.

---

```
public class GenericTest
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        // Call the methods as you please for a live Vs ser <-> de_ser run
    }

    private static Map<Long, Integer> generateHashMap()
    {
        Map<Long, Integer> map = new HashMap<Long, Integer>();
        final Random random = new Random();
        for(int counter = 0 ; counter < 10000000 ; counter++)
        {
            final int value = random.nextInt();
            final long key = random.nextLong();
            map.put(key, value);
        }
        return map;
    }

    private static void lookupItems(int n, Map<Long, Integer> map)
    {
        final Random random = new Random();
        for(int counter = 0 ; counter < n ; counter++)
        {
            final long key = random.nextLong();
            final Integer value = map.get(key);
        }
    }

    private static void serialize(Map<Long, Integer> map)
    {
        try
        {
            File file = new File("temp/omaha.ser");
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
            ObjectOutputStream s = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(f));
            s.writeObject(map);
            s.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static Map<Long, Integer> deserialize()
    {
        try
        {
            File file = new File("temp/omaha.ser");
            FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(file);
            ObjectInputStream s = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(f));
            HashMap<Long, Integer> map = (HashMap<Long, Integer>) s.readObject();
            s.close();
            return map;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> 300 million lookups take about 3.1 seconds when I create the hashmap myself, and about 8.5 seconds when I read the same hashmap from file. Does anybody have an idea why? Am I overlooking something obvious?

One possible cause is that the reconstructed HashMap may not have the same capacity (number of buckets) as the original one, which might increase the frequency of hash collisions or (if the size is increased) decrease locality of main memory access (resulting in more cache misses). To verify, use a debugger to inspect the length of map.table before and after reconstruction. If this is indeed the case, try copying the data into a new HashMap with an appropriate loadFactor.

As for why serialization does not maintain capacity: HashMap customizes its serialization format (it makes no sense to serialize null for every empty table element) by providing writeObject and readObject methods, and ignores the capacity it finds in the input stream:

```
/**
 * Reconstitute the {@code HashMap} instance from a stream (i.e.,
 * deserialize it).
 */
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream s)
    throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // Read in the threshold (ignored), loadfactor, and any hidden stuff
    s.defaultReadObject();
    reinitialize();
    if (loadFactor <= 0 || Float.isNaN(loadFactor))
        throw new InvalidObjectException("Illegal load factor: " +
                                         loadFactor);
    s.readInt();                // Read and ignore number of buckets
    int mappings = s.readInt(); // Read number of mappings (size)
    if (mappings < 0)
        throw new InvalidObjectException("Illegal mappings count: " +
                                         mappings);
    else if (mappings > 0) { // (if zero, use defaults)
        // Size the table using given load factor only if within
        // range of 0.25...4.0
        float lf = Math.min(Math.max(0.25f, loadFactor), 4.0f);
        float fc = (float)mappings / lf + 1.0f;
        int cap = ((fc < DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY) ?
                   DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY :
                   (fc >= MAXIMUM_CAPACITY) ?
                   MAXIMUM_CAPACITY :
                   tableSizeFor((int)fc));
        float ft = (float)cap * lf;
        threshold = ((cap < MAXIMUM_CAPACITY && ft < MAXIMUM_CAPACITY) ?
                     (int)ft : Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes","unchecked"})
            Node<K,V>[] tab = (Node<K,V>[])new Node[cap];
        table = tab;

        // Read the keys and values, and put the mappings in the HashMap
        for (int i = 0; i < mappings; i++) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                K key = (K) s.readObject();
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                V value = (V) s.readObject();
            putVal(hash(key), key, value, false, false);
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect it ignores the number of buckets to prevent a denial of service attack where an attacker crafts a serialization stream, and gives an unrealistically high (or low) number of buckets, which would cause an OutOfMemoryError (or excessive CPU load due to hash collisions), which would be a cheap way to do a denial of service attack against any application accepting serialized data from unstrusted sources ([CVE-2012-2739](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2012-2739) describes such an issue).

Comment: My `java.util.HashMap` takes this into account -  `// Read in number of buckets and allocate the bucket array;
 int numBuckets = s.readInt();
 table = new Entry[numBuckets];`. Then again I'd expect the `Map` to be re-hashed when the number of entries exceed the product of the capacity and load factor. As long as the hashing algorithm is the same, the number of collisions post creation of the object should remain the same as the buckets inside the HashMap grow with time.

Comment: The quoted source code is from jdk1.8.0_05/src.zip. Where is yours from? Also, the code I posted above uses putVal to add the mappings to the table, which neither checks the threshold nor resizes the table. Therefore, the table would only resize if additional mappings were added after deserialization.

Comment: I was quoting `JDK 1.6`. You're right that these values have been ignored in later versions. I ran the test again in JDK 1.7.25 and JDK 1.8.31 and the values remain comparable. `1152` ms on 1.7.25 and `1127` ms on 1.8.31.  I'm unaware of how `putVal` works since it is absent in `JDK 1.7.25` and new to me, but that change does not seem to have affected performance.